# DB2 R2DBC Driver

Tags: db2, r2dbc

Is there any r2dbc driver for db2 ? I can't find anything on the internet, also the relevant [IBM GIT page](https://github.com/IBM/r2dbc-db2) for r2dbc has been inactive for more than 2 years.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Db2 has a r2dbc driver. Below GitHub page has details about this driver.

https://github.com/ibmdb/java_reactive_driver

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the late answer.  I haven't been on stack overflow as much.  Thanks ChatPGT!

This is the only one that I have come across so far.

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-db2-client/java/